# Debug use step over extrmely slow in zulu-openjdk 8 on apple m1

Tags: java, debugging

I have done this test

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("start");
        test();                    //put breakpoint here
        System.out.println("end");
    }

    public static void test() {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("cost time:" + (t2 - t1));
    }
```

BouncyCastleProvider is from maven

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <version>1.68</version>
</dependency>
```

I put a breakpoint at `test()` line. and then `step over`. the test() method cost very much time.

1. debug with **zulu-openjdk 8**,use **step over** ,test() cost time is 30331ms
2. debug with **oracle jdk 17**,use **step over**, test() cost time is 837ms
3. debug with **zulu-openjdk 8** ,use **resume** ,test() cost time is 93ms
4. debug with **oracle jdk 17**,use **resume**,test() cost time is 85ms

use zulu-openjdk8 ,step over is too slow;
my device is macbookpro 2021 apple m1 pro

Comment: Have you verified whether that JDK is built for Intel chips rather than Apple Silicon? Perhaps running a debugger through [Rosetta 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)#Rosetta_2) is slow.

Comment: Yes,the jdk I used is for Apple silicon.`zulu8.62.0.19-ca-jdk8.0.332-macosx_aarch64`

Comment: I also test openjdk8 for arm linux. Have the same problem. I think it's a common bug in openjdk8 for aarch64. Because zulu8-for-m1 is also build from it and extend the problem from it. Now i switch to zulu11-for-m1 and the problem is missing. openjdk11 seems has good compatibility with jdk8.

Comment: It appears to be related to https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8307531.